# Do I always need to provide amount when charging a customer?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Simple question about Stripe Payment. If I've the SKU id of the product that the customer want to buy. Can I request the API using only that parameter for charge him or should I add some other informations like `amount` for example ?

I ask because I didn't found any example using only the SKU id and on the other hand I don't understand why that id wouldn't be sufficient for process the purchase of the product.

Answer (score 0):

[SKUs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/skus) are only useable with the [Orders](https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders) API. When creating [Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges) or [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents), you must use `amount` instead.